# Replace decimal with comma in multiple text files

Tags: python, r

I have 10 TAB delimited txt files in a folder. It has three columns (with numbers only) preceeded by a 21 line header (text and numbers). In order to process them further, I would like to :

1. Choose the second column from all text files (starting after the 21 line header; i attached figure with arrow), convert the comma into decimal and stack each of these columns from the 10 files into a new tab delimited/csv file. Once all files.

I know very little scripting. I have Rstudio and Python and have tried to fiddle around a bit. But I have really no clue what to do. Since I have to process multiple folders, my work would be really simplified if it could be possible.

[Reference figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5yrO.png)

Comment: So you just need to grab that column and concatenate it, with the comma replaced? You can throw away the header and other columns, and your output should be a big file containing just one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your requirements it sounds like this Python code should do the trick:

```
import os
import glob

DIR = "path/to/your/directory"
OUTPUT_FILE = "path/to/your/output.csv"
HEADER_SIZE = 21

input_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(DIR, "*.txt"))

for input_file in input_files:
    print("Now processing", input_file)

    # read the file
    with open(input_file, "r") as h:
        contents = h.readlines()

    # drop header
    contents = contents[HEADER_SIZE:]

    # grab the 2nd column
    column = []
    for row in contents:
        # stop at the footer
        if "####" in row:
            break

        split = row.split("\t")

        if len(split) >= 2:
            column.append(split[1])

    # replace the comma
    column_replaced = [row.replace(",", ".") for row in column]

    # append to the output file
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "a") as h:
        h.write("\n".join(column_replaced))
        h.write("\n")  # end on a newline
```

Note that this will discard everything that wasn't part of the second column in the output file.

Comment: Thanks John! Can i use this script directly in Python? Or do i need some libraries?

Comment: @AdityaIyer nope, no dependencies. Just adjust the paths. The `os` library is a Python built-in.

Comment: I tried and there is no response. Shouldnt the script have something like create csv or something like that? https://imgur.com/a/iUTeJy5

Comment: The script assumed that everything in the directory was an input file, which I see is not the case. I'll make an edit. But in any case you should have seen output. What command did you use to run it?

Comment: @AdityaIyer Edited. Do you see any output being printed?

Comment: I got this when i "Run the module"                                                              ================ RESTART: D:\Raw data\2018\CD spectra\test.py ================
Now processing D:/Raw data/2018/CD spectra/test\10 uM WT-syn F 1.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Raw data\2018\CD spectra\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    column = [row.split("\t")[1] for row in contents]
  File "D:\Raw data\2018\CD spectra\test.py", line 21, in <listcomp>
    column = [row.split("\t")[1] for row in contents]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>

Comment: Hmmm, is the header always 21 lines long? Are your files actually delimited by tabs ("\t") or actually by 4 spaces or something?

I've added an extra check but if the files are according to your spec then this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: the header is always 21 rows. they are tab delimited as ar as i can see.. I attached a dropbox link of my raw file... https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5jh8e4dnewiprs/10%20uM%20WT-syn%20F%201.txt?dl=0

Comment: Now it worked! But i see the output.csv file. The only thing is i see that the columns are not next to each other but below each other...and only the header from the first file was removed. hereby the output file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1l74y3dc5eixjez/output.csv?dl=0

Comment: Your file has a bunch of other formatted lines at the end of it. I assumed that it was just a tsv with a header, but all that other stuff at the bottom is causing the problem. You're going to have to give more information about how the files are formatted. Is this Extended Information always there? Is there always a blank line before it? Is it always preceeded with `#####`?

Comment: You wanted something to "stack each of these columns from the 10 files"...

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake. I didnt see that before. But yes, all files have the exact format of the extended information. there is always a blank line before it.After the extended information line, there are 65 lines of text. That can be removed too. and yes they are always preceded with #####

Comment: I've made an edit, but your use case is getting complicated enough that it's a bit too much for one SO answer

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not an exact solution but if you follow along its lines you will be close to what you need.

```
output <- "NewFileName.txt"

old_dir <- setwd("your/folder")
files <- list.files("\\.txt")
df_list <- lapply(files, read.table, skip = 21, sep = "\t")
x <- lapply(df_list, '[[', 2)
x <- gsub(",", ".", unlist(x))
write.table(x, output, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
setwd(old_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list =[]
filename = "my_text"
file = open(filename, "r")
for line in file:
    res=line.replace(",", ".")
    list.append(res)
    print(res)

f = open(filename, "w")
for item in list:
    f.write(item)`enter code here`
```

Comment: This would only process a single file, not the entire directory. It does not skip the header. it does not write a delimited file back to disk.